# Check out a git commit including submodules as they were at that time

Tags: git, git-submodules

How do we check out a git commit including submodules **as they were at that time**?

One reason why we might want this is to look at a previous version of the main program for which we need to rebuild it with the submodules in the version that was used at the time of the commit.

Given this, we could even use this in regular workflow:

- First update all submodules with `git submodule update --remote --merge`, then try to build to see if the program can work with the newest version of all submodules.
- If it works we are done. If it does not work, then we could go to the previous version of the program incl. the submodule-versions it used and with which it works.
- Then update the submodules one-by-one and change the program to work with them.

We can kind-of do it by manually looking at each submodule: which commit had the appropriate timestamp (and hope that the program used the then-most-uptodate version). It would be much better if we could see commit X of the program used submodule commit Y. And check those out for each submodule.

Comment: This is a cop-out, but if you need this functionality you could always in source the submodule code and bring it into the main repository.  Just giving this as an option in case you don't get an answer.

Comment: Ok, I would do that if there are no real solutions. Drawbacks: if I just copy the code, then I can not fetch. If I clone such that I have nested git repos then the main project would ignore any changes inside the sub-repo (it sees that there is a .git in that directory and thinks it makes sense to thus ignore it). I am looking into [subtree](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) and [subtree merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_subtree_merge) to see if that is what I need.

Comment: "It would be much better if we could see commit X of the program used submodule commit Y. And check those out for each submodule." But that's *exactly how submodules work by default*. The superproject records, in each commit, the *commit ID* of each submodule. Check out the superproject, move to commit X, update the submodules (without `--remote` etc), and they move to their commits as detached HEAD checkouts.

Comment: @torek I read that in the documentation as well, however when I check out the program at an old version, and then do `git submodule update --merge` then it responds `Already up-to-date.`, and when I then look at the submodule files they are still new instead of the old version corresponding to the program's commit

Comment: Don't use `--merge`, use `--checkout`. (This is the "default default" but perhaps you have overridden it.)

Comment: @torek That seems to work! If you write this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, you just need to run `git submodule update --checkout` (no `--merge`, no `--remote`) after checking out a previous commit.

There is a lot of confusion around submodules.  The basics are actually fairly simple though:

- Each submodule is its own Git repository.
- From the submodule, one refers to the "containing" Git as a *superproject*.
- The superproject records the URL and path—these being things you would normally control or provide by running `git clone`—for each of its submodules in the `.gitmodules` file.
- Meanwhile, when you make a commit in the superproject, this commit contains, in its snapshot, all the normal trees and files as usual, but also, for each submodule, the commit ID to check out when checking out the submodule.<sup>1</sup>

This has the effect of "freezing" the appropriate submodule commit into each superproject commit.  It is—or was originally—intended to manage third party code, where the submodule itself changes rarely compared to the superproject.

This model is not at all flexible, and is not suitable for the way many people *want* to use submodules, which is to keep them at the tip of some branch.  So submodules grew the ability to update to branch names, or to be worked-in and have the work rebased and/or merged.  These new abilities spawned the `submodule.name.update` configuration entries and `git submodule update --remote` options.

*If you have not configured any of these items*, `git submodule update` alone will check out the desired (recorded) submodule commits for each submodule recorded in the current, i.e., `HEAD`, commit of the superproject.  If you *have* configured some of these, you can use `git submodule update --checkout` to override the configuration and cause a `git checkout hash-id` in each submodule.  Note that adding `--force` makes Git do this submodule checkout even if the `HEAD` is already at that entry.  But since each submodule is its own Git repository, the submodule's checkout has its own interaction with its own (per-repository / per-work-tree) index and work-tree.<sup>2</sup>

Again, every submodule is its own Git repository, which means a submodule of the current superproject may have submodules of its own.  If so, this makes the submodule a superproject as well, and this is where the `--recursive` flag comes in.  If you are not nesting submodules, none of this complexity will affect you.

---

<sup>1</sup>In other words, the *index* for the superproject has an entry for each submodule.  The type of this index entry is "gitlink", which stores the SHA-1 read from `HEAD` in the submodule.  These gitlink entries are treated as sort of a weird cross between a symlink and a directory.

<sup>2</sup>In other words, if you have manually entered one of the submodules and modified the index and/or work-tree, the `git checkout` run *inside* that submodule, if any, may still carry your modifications into the new checked-out commit.